# Check where page is being accessed from

Tags: php, php-5.6

I have two PHP Pages, an index.php and a content.php.  I am using the code `include("content.php");` on the index.php file. Is it possible to check whether the user is on index.php or did he go straight to content.php ?

Basically what I want to do is display content.php on index.php but if the user went directly to content.php then I don't want the script to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the page that you want to only be included

```
<?php
if(!defined('MyConst')) {
    die('Direct access not permitted');
}
?>
```

then on the pages that include it add

```
<?php
    define('MyConst', TRUE);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**index.php**

```
$chk = 1
include("content.php");
```

**content.php**

```
if ($chk < 1){
  include('index.php');
  exit;
}
```